# Firebase authentication is login just latest registered user

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a login system and also applying authentication. But only the latest registered user can successfully login but the rest users cannot login. Here is the code down below:

```
package com.example.finalyearproject_universityhub;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ImageView search, menu;
        TextView goToLogin;
        Button login;
        EditText email, password;

        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menu = findViewById(R.id.menu);
        search = findViewById(R.id.search);
        goToLogin = findViewById(R.id.goToLogin);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        goToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateUserAccountActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                userLogin();
            }
        });

    }

    private void userLogin() {
        String userEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String userPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if(userEmail.isEmpty()){
            email.setError("Email is required");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        else if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(userEmail).matches()){
            email.setError("Please provide valid Email");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        else if(userPassword.isEmpty()){
            password.setError("Password is required");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        else if(userPassword.length()< 6){
            password.setError("Min password should b 6 characters");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

//        else if (userEmail.equals("admin1@gmail.com") && userPassword.equals("admin1") || userEmail.equals("admin2@gmail.com") && userPassword.equals("admin2") ){
//            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdminMainActivity.class));
//        }

        else {
           mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
                   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               FirebaseUser users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                               if (users != null) {
                                   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                                           .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                   for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                       if (snapshot1.exists()) {
                                                           UserModelClass userModelClass = snapshot1.getValue(UserModelClass.class);
                                                           if (userModelClass.getUserEmail().equals(userEmail)) {
                                                               if (userModelClass.getUserPassword().equals(userPassword)) {
                                                                   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class));
                                                               } else {
                                                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This account don't exist. 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                               }
                                                           } else {
                                                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email or password is wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                         else {
                                                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This account don't exist. 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                               }

                                               @Override
                                               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                               }
                                           });
//                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               } else{
                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to login! Please check your credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                           } else {
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This account don't exist. 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }
                   });
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the model class below:

```
package com.example.finalyearproject_universityhub;

public class UserModelClass {

    String user;
    String fullName;
    String userName;

    String gender;

    String DOB;
    String countryName;
    String countryIos;
    String countryCode;
    String contactNum;

    String userEmail;
    String userPassword;

    public UserModelClass(){

    }

    public UserModelClass(String user, String fullName, String userName, String gender, String countryName, String countryIos, String countryCode, String contactNum, String userEmail, String userPassword) {
        this.user = user;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.countryIos = countryIos;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.contactNum = contactNum;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }


    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public String getCountryIos() {
        return countryIos;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public String getContactNum() {
        return contactNum;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }
}
```

When I click on login button if the email and password where the latest registered user then it will b login and intent to next activity but if the user is not the latest registered then the toast that appear is: **This account don't exist. 3**.
In the image given below are some registered users. From these 3 only the email: iqragull902@gmail.com is logging in, the rest of these are not, they show the toast.

[image]

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for asking. There is no error in this code. I have just restarted the android studio and reinstalled the app and now the same code is working properly.